# Comprobar filas SQL afectadas en PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Tengo el siguiente código en PHP

```
$sql = $db->prepare( **procedimiento** );
$sql->execute();

if($sql->rowCount()>=1){
 return true;
}else{
 return false;
}
```

El código funcionaba muy bien, pero ahora en `$sql->rowCount()` me está retornando 0 cuando en la base de datos si ha guardado los cambio.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la query que ejecutas?

Comment: Además la doc. expone como alternativa usar [fetchColumn](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php#refsect1-pdostatement.rowcount-examples) (*léase el ejemplo #2 donde además se expone el por que de la sugerencia*)

Comment: [La documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php) indica claramente que `rowCount()` es para consultas INSERT, UPDATE o DELETE. Si es una consulta SELECT, aunque funciona en algunos SGBD en otros no, por lo que la doc lo desaconseja para estos casos. Para SELECT debes usar un SELECT COUNT(*) o bien recuperar los datos y verificar la variable en la que los recoges para saber si la consulta trajo resultados. Sin saber precisamente qué tipo de consulta hay en `**procedimiento**` no podemos responder a tu pregunta.

Comment: Lo que ejecutó es un procedimiento que solo realiza un insert.

Comment: Y se que se igual es mejor usar ```fetchColum``` pero en este caso hay otro error al usarlo, por eso se optó por usar el ```rowCount``` sin embargo todo funcionaba bien peor simplemente dejo de funcionar y al tratar de usar el ```ferchColum``` me da un error con el objeto ```PDOStatement```